# Mezclar jquery con php botón no funciona

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Os cuento, tengo un `script` que al pulsar sobre un botón me genera un `select` el cual quiero que me aparezca rellenado con datos de la base de datos.

El problema es que lo mezclo con `php`, ya que el `WHERE` de la consulta lo mando desde otro formulario de la misma página, haciendo que el `select` obtenga valores y claro el botón en el momento que lo pulso no funciona. Si quito la parte `php` funciona correctamente, pero sin valores.

He probado a ponerlo todo dentro del `script` pero con las comillas se vuelve un poco loco y no muestra resultado tampoco. ¿Hay alguna forma posible de hacer esto?

```
$(container).append('<input type="text" name="" style="width:50px"><select><option>Selecciona regla:</option>'+<?php

                $insertar = "SELECT DISTINCT proveedor FROM dbo.exclusiones_datos";
                $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insertar);

                while($roww = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='".$roww['id']."''>".$roww['Exclusion']." - ".$roww['Operador']." - ".$roww['Valor']."</option>";           
                }

            ?>+'</select><hr>');
```

Actualizo el tema, estoy probando con `ajax`, pero no se muy bien recoger el valor de un solo `option` ya que estos se generan dinámicamente según el contenido de la base de datos. Con `ajax` consigo mandar de un `input` a otro información pero se me pasa toda la información del `SELECT`, si hay 3 datos, mandan los 3 datos, pero no respetando sus posiciones, quiero decir aparece un solo `OPTION` con todos los datos, en vez de 3

Aquí os dejo el código con la última modificación:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var opcion = document.getElementById('selector').value;
    $("#selec").click(function(){
        $.post("prueba.php", function(opcion){
            $("#opti").html(opcion);
        })
    })
})
</script>
<body>
        <select name="proveedores" id="selector">
    <?php
        $contador = 0;
        $insertar = "SELECT * FROM dbo.exclusiones_datos WHERE Proveedor = 'Samsung'";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insertar);

        while($roww = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            $contador++;
            echo "<option id='$contador' value='".$roww['id']."''>".$roww['Exclusion']." - ".$roww['Operador']." - ".$roww['Valor']."</option>";            
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Seleccionar" id="selec">
<select>
    <option id="opti"></option>
</select>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te aparece un solo `option` con todos los datos porque estas actualizando el `option` y no el `select`

`$("#opti").html(opcion);`

De esa manera lo que estas haciendo es poner el contenido que obtuviste por ajax, dentro del `option#opti`.

Lo que deberias hacer es darle un id o clase al `select` para poder referenciarlo

```
<select id="select-to-update">
    <option id="opti"></option>
</select>
```

y luego de obtener los datos por ajax, deberias insertarlo en el select:

`$("#select-to-update").html(opcion);`

Es importante que si lo haces de esta manera, la info que deberias obtener mediante el ajax, sea el html de los options en plano, ya que lo que estas haciendo es escribir el contenido del ajax directamente del select.

Es decir, esto funcionaria siempre y cuando tu ajax `prueba.php` devuelva algo como:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
```